# Can we ignore the daily rep limit while during private beta?

Tags: discussion, reputation

When sites go public, we're going to need people who can vote to close / migrate questions, especially considering the overlap between this site and others.

In order for that to happen, several people are going to need to garner enough reputation for the system to trust them enough to do that, within 7 days. Otherwise, moderators are going to be doing what the community should be doing.

Can we either extend the private beta to allow sufficient time for people to hit 3k, or perhaps relax the daily rep limit so that when the site goes into public beta, at least a few people will be (close to being) able to cast such votes?

Or, perhaps this is by design?

**Edit**

I'm not suggesting getting rid of the daily rep cap on all sites. I'm just wondering how members of the community can earn enough reputation in seven days to be able to effectively manage the site once its public, this is my first private beta :)

Apparently this has been addressed, which is why I also asked if this was by design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the WebApps public beta, "Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions" is at 500 rep.  There seems to be the super low private beta rep requirements, low public beta rep requirements, and then presumably the standard level once the beta is over and the site is public.

Comment: Thanks :) That completely addresses my concern. It is, indeed, by design.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by others, the better way to handle this is to relax rep requirements for private (very low) and public (somewhat lower) which we have done. Check the respective site `/faq`s for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but -1.

I feel the reputation cap is extremely important. If you want to do something decrease the amount of rep required to close questions, but don't mess with the reputation cap.

Comment: Even during the private beta? My concern is that there won't be enough people with sufficient capacity to vote to close questions in order to keep the site on topic. Once its public, of course, restore the cap.

Comment: @Tim: in the private beta you only need 1 rep to cast close votes

Comment: my concerns lie once the private beta has _finsihed_. We then have some users with 1k+, maybe 2k+, but none with sufficient reputation to cast close votes once the public can join.

Comment: its a non issue. Which is why I asked if this was, perhaps, by design :)